# How to structure the code correctly if I have 2 Angular components that have the same view but different logic?

Tags: javascript, angular, components, angular-components

I have such a situation, there are 2 components that are used in two different places, but their presentation is the same, but the logic is different. I want to have one component that will work differently depending on the situation. How do I structure my code to avoid duplicating components?

Answer (score 0):

You could read this article. It talks about template inheritance in Angular. It explains what you want achieve: https://medium.com/acute-angular/how-to-inherit-a-component-in-angular-and-reuse-its-template-88b9cbb4b55